# Query takes over 30 minutes -- How can I speed up? (Explain and schema included)

Tags: mysql, sql

Goal: **Display ethnicity data by district for each race and year as a percent of total.**

Problem: Query takes over 30 minutes to run. I would like to get this down to under 10 seconds. Is there another strategy to solve this problem that I am not thinking of?

Query:

```
SELECT field_data_field_district_id.field_district_id_value as district_id, year, race, ROUND(SUM(count)/(
SELECT SUM(count)
FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner
INNER JOIN field_data_field_school_id as field_data_field_school_id_inner ON field_data_field_school_id_inner.field_school_id_value = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.school_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_district as field_data_field_district_inner ON field_data_field_district_inner.entity_id = field_data_field_school_id_inner.entity_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_district_id as field_data_field_district_id_inner ON field_data_field_district_inner.field_district_nid = field_data_field_district_id_inner.entity_id
WHERE field_data_field_district_id_inner.field_district_id_value = field_data_field_district_id.field_district_id_value and
school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.year = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.year
) * 100 ,2) as percent 
FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw
INNER JOIN field_data_field_school_id ON field_data_field_school_id.field_school_id_value = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.school_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_district ON field_data_field_district.entity_id = field_data_field_school_id.entity_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_district_id ON field_data_field_district.field_district_nid = field_data_field_district_id.entity_id
GROUP BY district_id, year, race
```

Explain:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                                | type | possible_keys                | key                | key_len | ref                                                                | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | field_data_field_district_id         | ALL  | entity_id                    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               |   685 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | field_data_field_district            | ref  | entity_id,field_district_nid | field_district_nid | 5       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_id.entity_id       |     3 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | field_data_field_school_id           | ref  | entity_id                    | entity_id          | 4       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district.entity_id          |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw       | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               | 97098 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | field_data_field_district_id_inner   | ALL  | entity_id                    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               |   685 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | field_data_field_district_inner      | ref  | entity_id,field_district_nid | field_district_nid | 5       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_id_inner.entity_id |     3 | Using where; Using index        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | field_data_field_school_id_inner     | ref  | entity_id                    | entity_id          | 4       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_inner.entity_id    |     1 |                                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner | ref  | year                         | year               | 4       | func                                                               | 32366 | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Tables:

school_data_race_ethnicity_raw - (Approx. 100,000 rows)

```
mysql> show create table school_data_race_ethnicity_raw;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| school_data_race_ethnicity_raw | CREATE TABLE `school_data_race_ethnicity_raw` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `school_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `race` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `school_id` (`school_id`,`year`),
  KEY `year` (`year`,`race`),
  KEY `school_id_2` (`school_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=97099 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

field_data_field_school_id - Approx. 5000 rows

```
mysql> show create table field_data_field_school_id;
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                      | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| field_data_field_school_id | CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_school_id` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_school_id_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_school_id_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_school_id_format` (`field_school_id_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 234 (field_school_id)' |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

field_data_field_district - Approx. 5000 rows

```
mysql> show create table field_data_field_district;
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| field_data_field_district | CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_district` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_district_nid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_district_nid` (`field_district_nid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 221 (field_district)' |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

field_data_field_district_id - Approx: 1000 rows

```
mysql> show create table field_data_field_district_id;
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                        | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| field_data_field_district_id | CREATE TABLE `field_data_field_district_id` (
  `entity_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The entity type this data is attached to',
  `bundle` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The field instance bundle to which this row belongs, used when deleting a field instance',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this data item has been deleted',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The entity id this data is attached to',
  `revision_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The entity revision id this data is attached to, or NULL if the entity type is not versioned',
  `language` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The language for this data item.',
  `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The sequence number for this data item, used for multi-value fields',
  `field_district_id_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_district_id_format` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),
  KEY `entity_type` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`),
  KEY `language` (`language`),
  KEY `field_district_id_format` (`field_district_id_format`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Data storage for field 218 (field_district_id)' |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

NOTE: The only table I can change is school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as the others are generated by drupal.

```
mysql> explain SELECT field_data_field_district_id_inner.field_district_id_value,
    ->             school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.year,
    ->             SUM(count) as total
    ->         FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner
    ->         INNER JOIN field_data_field_school_id as field_data_field_school_id_inner 
    ->             ON field_data_field_school_id_inner.field_school_id_value 
    ->                 = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.school_id
    ->         INNER JOIN field_data_field_district as field_data_field_district_inner 
    ->             ON field_data_field_district_inner.entity_id 
    ->                 = field_data_field_school_id_inner.entity_id
    ->         INNER JOIN field_data_field_district_id as field_data_field_district_id_inner 
    ->             ON field_data_field_district_inner.field_district_nid 
    ->                 = field_data_field_district_id_inner.entity_id
    ->     GROUP BY field_district_id_value, year
    -> ;
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                                | type | possible_keys                | key                | key_len | ref                                                                | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | field_data_field_district_id_inner   | ALL  | entity_id                    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               |   773 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | field_data_field_district_inner      | ref  | entity_id,field_district_nid | field_district_nid | 5       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_id_inner.entity_id |     3 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | field_data_field_school_id_inner     | ref  | entity_id                    | entity_id          | 4       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_inner.entity_id    |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               | 97098 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you remove the [dependent] subqueries?

Comment: You deserve an up-vote for the question title alone.

Comment: (And what I mean by that, is move it -- the "sum stuff" -- out into a separate derived join table, which is a common way to handle this without nicer partitioning functions. I would suspect MySQL is running that SUM *for each* grouped record, and not implicitly/magically promoting it to a JOIN -- but I don't use MySQL and don't understand its query plan output or optimizer ;-)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to create a derived table with the SUM stuff?

Comment: Instead of a DESCRIBE... could you post the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE for each of your tables?  It will help give us an idea of how the indexes are laid out.

Comment: Ok, I would suggest creating the following index:  CREATE INDEX ix_field_school_id_value ON field_data_field_school_id(field_school_id_value);

Comment: Also, all of your tables are InnoDB with utf8 as the charset except for school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.  I would suggest converting that table over to InnoDB and setting utf8 as the charset.  I think that could be slowing down the join between that table and the school table.

Comment: I can't create indexes on those tables as they are generated by Drupal.

Comment: Manually adding indexes to the tables won't prevent Drupal queries from running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT field_data_field_district_id.field_district_id_value as district_id,
    x.year,
    race,
    ROUND(SUM(count)/(x.total) * 100 , 2) as percent 
FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw
INNER JOIN field_data_field_school_id 
    ON field_data_field_school_id.field_school_id_value 
        = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.school_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_district 
    ON field_data_field_district.entity_id 
        = field_data_field_school_id.entity_id
INNER JOIN field_data_field_district_id 
    ON field_data_field_district.field_district_nid 
        = field_data_field_district_id.entity_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT field_data_field_district_id_inner.field_district_id_value,
            school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.year,
            SUM(count) as total
        FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner
        INNER JOIN field_data_field_school_id as field_data_field_school_id_inner 
            ON field_data_field_school_id_inner.field_school_id_value 
                = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.school_id
        INNER JOIN field_data_field_district as field_data_field_district_inner 
            ON field_data_field_district_inner.entity_id 
                = field_data_field_school_id_inner.entity_id
        INNER JOIN field_data_field_district_id as field_data_field_district_id_inner 
            ON field_data_field_district_inner.field_district_nid 
                = field_data_field_district_id_inner.entity_id
    GROUP BY field_district_id_value, year
) x ON x.field_district_id_value = field_data_field_district_id.field_district_id_value 
    AND x.year = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.year
GROUP BY district_id, x.year, race
```

I basically moved your query that calculates the total count for each district/year out of the SELECT and into another JOIN.

Explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                                | type | possible_keys                | key                | key_len | ref                                                                | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | field_data_field_district_id         | ALL  | entity_id                    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               |   773 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | field_data_field_district            | ref  | entity_id,field_district_nid | field_district_nid | 5       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_id.entity_id       |     3 | Using where; Using index        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | field_data_field_school_id           | ref  | entity_id                    | entity_id          | 4       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district.entity_id          |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>                           | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               |  1902 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw       | ref  | year                         | year               | 4       | x.year                                                             | 32366 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | field_data_field_district_id_inner   | ALL  | entity_id                    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               |   773 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | field_data_field_district_inner      | ref  | entity_id,field_district_nid | field_district_nid | 5       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_id_inner.entity_id |     3 | Using where; Using index        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | field_data_field_school_id_inner     | ref  | entity_id                    | entity_id          | 4       | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.field_data_field_district_inner.entity_id    |     1 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner | ALL  | NULL                         | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                                                               | 97098 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+--------------------------------------+------+------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
9 rows in set (4 min 0.59 sec)
```

Comment: may I contribute with a bit shorter version of this (using shorter aliases): http://pastebin.com/8GZjm9TN

Comment: The query has been running for 4 minutes and still isn't done. Not sure how long it is going to take

Comment: Could you post the explain output for the query?

Comment: The explain has been running for 4 minutes now... (also)

Comment: Hmmm... can you get an explain on just the subquery?

Comment: Explain came back with :
Column 'year' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I explained the subquery and put in my original post.

Comment: I changed my query to (hopefully) resolve the "'year' in field list is ambiguous" error.

Comment: I am running explain now. I have updated my question to include show create table statements

Comment: The explain took 4 minutes. I have edited your question to show it. If the explain took 4 minutes the query will probably take longer.

Comment: Now I must think that the problem does not reside in your query but anywhere else.  Do other queries run normally?